# What happened to my marigold plant how it can be made healthy again?

Tags: watering, transplanting, sunlight, marigold

I transplanted it yesterday but now it's leaves are curled and is bending downwards. What should I do? Whenever I transplant a plant it usually gets in same condition and slowly dies. Please help me, I do not want to lose this plant.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some images of the plant.

Comment: Can you also add where you are in the world and what your temperatures outdoors are like currently (assuming the plant is outdoors).